# IBM Watson SpeechToText punctuation

Tags: speech-to-text, ibm-watson, punctuation

I'm new to IBM Watson SpeechToText and I need to use it in a project but I've seen that the returned transcription doesn't have any punctuation. I've enabled smart formatting but it doesn't work. 
Any suggestions?

> For US English, the feature also directs the service to substitute punctuation symbols for the keyword strings in the audio.

[IBM docs](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/speech-to-text/output.html#output)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi @l22dev the service does not provide punctuation at the moment, punctuation is not part of the smart formatting feature.